# get available wallets from solana-wallet-adapter

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

gm,
i am trying to get a list of available wallets to connect via
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets
v.0.19.24

my integration code looks like that:

```
import { UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
provideWalletAdapter({
  autoConnect: false,
  adapters: [new UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter()],
}),
```

at this point, I would expect to get a list of all available wallet extensions I have & follow **wallet-standart**, but all I see is the burner wallet.

any idea what is missing?

thx

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md has some more information, maybe you can start by getting this example to work, and then adapting your code to do the same thing?